# How do I set default values for all data types in Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model that does not provide default values for any of its properties. I have this model bound to the template and I would like to save the model on transition **only if it's dirty**. However, simply entering a text field then leaving the text field will cause the record to become dirty, because it previously was null/undefined and now it's an empty string. I was wondering if there is a simple work-around for this?

Model:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  myProperty: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Route:

```
App.MyModelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var modelIsDirty = this.get('currentModel.isDirty');

      if (modelIsDirty) {
        console.log('dirty model!');
      }
      else {
        console.log('not dirty');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
{{input type="text" value=model.myProperty}}
```

If I simply focus/blur the input, this will cause the record to become dirty. Is there a way to set the default value for any string property to be '' instead of `null` or `undefined`? I think that may fix the problem.

I am aware of the `defaultValue` property, but I have 15 models and some have 40+ properties each. I would like to avoid setting a `defaultValue` for every single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, your server is returning null or undefined for some properties in your model which should be strings? I had some similar issue where I sometimes wanted the property to be null instead of an empty string. Instead of modifying the model class, I solved this by adding an observer to the Ember textfield class:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
    nullable: false,

    nullableObserver: function() {
        if (this.get('nullable') && this.get('value') === '') {
            this.set('value', null);
        }
    }.observes('value')
});
```

With the above code I can than make a text field nullable by setting its nullable property to true:

```
{{input type="text" value=someValue nullable=true}}
```

Or you can omit the nullable property in the above code and set it to null by default for all input fields.

Comment: I like this approach. Thank you!!